# Restore domain joined encrypted VMs

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are trying to restore an encrypted VM in Azure, but the question is if we do will it not conflict on the domain as we build out the VM? Will there not be two guest level VMs registering with the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Alex, an Azure Independent Advisor and user like you. I'm happy to help today.

When restoring this encrypted VM, simply disable the network interface until you are ready to deploy it on the domain.

If I misunderstood your question, please provide additional details.

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: thanks for the information, but how would I disable an interface in azure, I would need the interface enabled to access the VMs over rdp? I was thinking more about blocking domain traffic using NSGs maybe?